# Testing APNS with Appstore production certificate

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, production-environment

I am depending on push notification services in my iPhone app, and tested with development and ad-hoc production certificates it is working fine. But when I submit the app to the App Store, I have to create Appstore production certificate, is there any way to test APNS with this certificate before publishing the application to Apple.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the actual problem. Using the Appstore production profile, we can create an .ipa file but we cannot install it on the device directly, it has to come from Appstore. It can only be uploaded to the App Store. So, the problem is as we cannot install the package on iPhone we cannot send the push notifications to test it before submitting the package to Appstore. So, technically it is not possible to test the set-up. I was just curious to know if somebody cracked it.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11149083)

Comment: This is not additional comment, it is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to Package an Ad Hoc distribution which provides an .ipa for iOS devices that I have specified in the Apple Developer Center.

I then send the .ipa to the specified devices using Diawi.com (which is an awesome service like test flight), but can be used prior to submitting to the app store (like the old test flight)

Answer (score -1):

The APNs production certificate is universal, so it does work in both development and distribution, see [Apple documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW11).

For the AppStore distribution certificate:

> Before uploading your app to iTunes Connect, optionally distribute it for testing on registered devices using an ad hoc provisioning profile or team provisioning profile.

Here's the whole run-through on how to achieve this: [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html).

Another option is using TestFlight, details can be found under the previous link.

Comment: The certificate is not universal, we need to have different certificates to test both development and production environments. But for Appstore production certificate is a third kind of certificate, but need to know how to test the package being uploaded with the same certificate.

Comment: @Krish I think I misunderstood your question. The APNs production certificate is universal, but were you asking about how to test APNs with an AppStore distribution cert?

Comment: Yes, before it is available on AppStore.

Comment: @Krish - see revised answer.

Comment: The production certificate is not universal. It does not work for developer environment. You are right TestFlight might be an option. Thanks.

Comment: @Krish - well, in any case, it is possible to install the binary on test devices [like this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW17)